# data-main, not able to load requirejs

Tags: javascript, nginx, requirejs

When loading `https://hub-dev.andatech.com.au.`

I got error in console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () main.js
```

Look into source code: I saw

```
<script data-main="https://hub-dev.andatech.com.au/script/main.js" src="https://hub-dev.andatech.com.au/assets/js/require.js"></script>
```

paste `https://hub-dev.andatech.com.au/script/main.js` into browser, it returns 404.

It seems requirejs is loading, could anyone shine some lights.

My nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name hub-dev.andatech.com.au www.hub-dev.andatech.com.au;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  include snippets/ssl-hub-dev.andatech.com.au.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  server_name hub-dev.andatech.com.au www.hub-dev.andatech.com.au;
  root /home/thehub/public_html;

  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you change the data-tag to data-main="script/main". You have a `main.js` file in a folder called `script` in the root of your project?

Comment: changed to data-main="script/main", not working. There is no physical file for main.js. A working example is this: https://hub.andatech.com.au/ui/login (production site)

Comment: The `data-main` attribute tells require.js to load `script/main.js` AFTER require.js loads. So yes, if there is no main.js present, a 404 will be the result. It is clearly present on the non-dev machine here: https://hub.andatech.com.au/script/main.js